# Trying to Create and Add Strings to a Arraylist in JNI

Tags: rust, java-native-interface

I have a rust vector of an unknown size only filled with Strings, which I try to pass to Java as an `Arraylist` with the JNI crate. Passing a `JArray` with `JStrings` (`getQuestionDetails`) works flawlessly (passing them in Rust and reading them in Java) and I have been able to get it to build an `Arraylist` (`getArrayList`) when adding and initializing with integers, but I just can't figure out how to add Strings and to initialize it correctly.

I know, that my code can't work with a `JValue` required at this position (docs: https://docs.rs/jni/0.9.3/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.call_method) and me passing a `JString`. So the compiler is of course correct when telling me:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:140:70
    |
140 |           env.call_method(arraylist, "add", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z", &[env.new_string(
    |  ______________________________________________________________________^
141 | |                 question_details_array
142 | |                     [1]
143 | |                 .to_owned(),
144 | |             )
145 | |             .unwrap()
146 | |             .to_owned()]
    | |_______________________^ expected enum `jni::wrapper::objects::jvalue::JValue`, found struct `jni::wrapper::objects::jstring::JString`
    |
    = note: expected type `jni::wrapper::objects::jvalue::JValue<'_>`
               found type `jni::wrapper::objects::jstring::JString<'_>`
```

I have seen that in the docs for [`JValue`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.4.2/jni/objects/enum.JValue.html), `JString` is not an accepted type, but I can't pass my string as a value and have found no way to convert my `JString` to a `JObject`.

My unsuccessful coding attempt:

lib.rs (full code: https://github.com/mad-de/lib_impp_android):

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
mod lib_impp;

use jni::objects::{JObject, JString, JValue};
use jni::sys::{jarray, jobject, jobjectArray, jstring};
use jni::JNIEnv;
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

// Return Arraylist - use Array as source for easier testing instead of Vec
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_getArraylist(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JObject,
    question_num: i32,
    jeopardy_mode: bool,
) -> jobject {
    let question_details_array: [String; 4] =
        lib_impp::get_mc_distractors(question_num, jeopardy_mode, &FILES_PATH);
    let cls_arraylist = env.find_class("java/util/ArrayList").unwrap();
    let arraylist = env.new_object(cls_arraylist, "()String", &[]).unwrap();
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 4 {
        // Add items
        env.call_method(
            arraylist,
            "add",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z",
            &[env
                .new_string(question_details_array[1].to_owned())
                .unwrap()
                .to_owned()],
        )
        .unwrap();
        i += 1;
    }
    *arraylist
}

// Return Array with a Question Element
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_getQuestionDetails(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JObject,
    question_num: i32,
) -> jarray {
    let question_details_array: [String; 4] =
        lib_impp::get_question_details(question_num, &FILES_PATH);
    // Initialize our array with 4 empty Strings
    let array: jobjectArray = env
        .new_object_array(
            4,
            env.find_class("java/lang/String").unwrap(),
            *env.new_string("").unwrap(),
        )
        .unwrap();
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 4 {
        // Edit every Item of the Array to give it the values we want
        env.set_object_array_element(
            array,
            i,
            *env.new_string(
                question_details_array
                    [usize::try_from(i).expect("Variable i could not be converted to usize.")]
                .to_owned(),
            )
            .unwrap()
            .to_owned(),
        )
        .expect("Could not perform set_object_array_element on array element.");
        i += 1;
    }
    array
}
```

So how can I pass a `Arraylist` with strings (`JStrings`)? I probably took a completely wrong turn somewhere, so many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> I […] have found no way to convert my `JString` to a `JObject`

The [documentation of `JObject`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.4.2/jni/objects/struct.JObject.html) clearly mentions that there is an

```rust
impl<'a> From<JString<'a>> for JObject<'a>
```

This means you can use `JObject::from(some_jstring)` or if type inference is clear `some_jstring.into()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's what I tried before - when trying to run
       // Add items
        env.call_method(
            arraylist,
            "add",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z",
            JObject::from(
                &env.new_string(question_details_array[1].to_owned())
                    .unwrap()
                    .to_owned(),
            ),
        )
        .unwrap();

It results in:

^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&jni::wrapper::objects::jstring::JString<'_>>` is not implemented for `jni::wrapper::objects::jobject::JObject<'_>

Comment: Why do you pass a reference? There is a `impl<'a> From<JString<'a>> for JObject<'a>`, not a `impl<'a> From<&'a JString<'a>> for JObject<'a>`.

Comment: You are certainly right - I rewrote it to:
    let cls_arraylist = env.find_class("java/util/ArrayList").unwrap();
    let arraylist = env.new_object(cls_arraylist, "()O", &[]).unwrap();
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 7 {
        // Add items
        env.call_method(
            arraylist,
            "add",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z",
            &[JValue::from(JObject::from(env.new_string("PETER".to_string()).unwrap()))],
        )
        .unwrap();
        i += 1;
    }'
But now it crashes with a SIGABRT when trying to access it as an Arraylist of Objects in Java.

Comment: The signature on your constructor is extremely suspect. The return type should be void (V), not O.